# Buttons to play Audio in Mechanical Turk

Tags: javascript, html, mechanicalturk

We would like to integrate audio in an Amazon Mechanical Turk HIT, with buttons to play and increase or decrease volume.

```
<audio id="player" src="test.mp3"></audio> 
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</button> 
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume += 0.1">Vol+ </button>  
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume -= 0.1">Vol- </button>
```

The problem is that any button press is also interpreted as a Submit and the HIT is submitted. How can that be avoided?

Comment: Seems like a good use case for an ExternalQuestion HIT, so you're not constrained by the MTurk interface.

Answer (score 2):

Uh, it seems like this is just being caused by a lack of understanding of the HTML `<button>` tag, not anything to do with Mechanical Turk.

All buttons submit a form by default unless they have the attribute `type="button"`.

This is because, [according to the HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.5), the default button type is `submit`.